# Clang-format not using .clang-format file ubuntu (no errors)

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I have a `.clang-format` in my project directory that houses my .cpp files and my build directory. From my terminal I cd into my project folder and run `clang-format -style=file -i *.cpp`. Here's my `.clang-format` file.

```
Language: Cpp
ColumnLimit: 0
BreakBeforeBraces: GNU
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
IndentCaseLabels: true
NamespaceIndentation: All
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
DerivePointerAlignment: false
PointerAlignment: Left
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
```

I'm testing the functionality by changing `BreakBeforeBraces` and nothing changes. It seems to be using a fallback formatting. What's going on? Is there a way to see what `clang-format` is actually doing?

Comment: Same problem here in Ubuntu 18.04. No matter where I put the `.clang_format` file, it is always ignored by `clang-format`

Comment: Same problem here on Manjaro. Even giving the filename and path as an argument to `-style=file:<FILENAME>` didn't work

Answer (score -1):

When using `-style=file`, clang-format for each input file will try to find the .clang-format file located in the closest **parent directory** of the input file. When the standard input is used, the search is started from the current directory.

You can use the command below to see the actual config used in the running directory

```
clang-format -style=file -dump-config
```